# Casting a date in MySQL returns the previous date

Tags: mysql, date, casting

I've got a doubt this question. Why MySQL is returning the previous date when doing this cast?.

```
select  cast('2019-06-26' as datetime) as date1, 
        cast('2019-06-26' as date) as date2,
        date_add(cast('2019-06-26' as date), interval 1 day) date3;
```

[image]

This behavior was affecting the final result of one of my reports. I solved the situation by adding a day. However, I would like to understand this result.

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

I would imagine that this is some sort of timezone issue.  Assuming that your timezone is some number of hours ahead of the timezone is which the MySQL server is located, MySQL might be adjusting backward those incoming dates to match the server timezone.

Try running the following query to find out what MySQL's server timezone is:

```
SELECT @@global.time_zone, @@session.time_zone;
```

Then, compare this against your current timezone.